# Is the kerning on my logo correct?

Tags: logo, typography, critique, kerning

I've been kerning this logo and I'd love input from those well versed on the subject.

I'm particularly interested with the space around the "f", but also appreciate any other kerning input or advice.

[image: Logo]

I've updated the logo kerning based on the advice given.

[image: Logo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F and L do look a little tight but I don’t think it’s too bad. I like the logo by the way.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the logo based on the advice given.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which font this is, but consider turning the F/L combo into a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) if that's available with your font. This joins the letters together and makes an optical correction to particular letter pairings, specifically because they are otherwise difficult to space correctly. Actually worth changing the font to another similar one with ligatures available. Everything else looks ok.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add a little space between "f" and "l". Plus, minus the space between graphical emblem and the logo text. It looks a bit off to the right in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the logo kerning based on the advice given. Not sure about the icon spacing. It may just be that I've looked at it for so long, but it looks off when I change it.

Comment: ummm.. okay just make sure it looks appealing to everyone in any case. lolz. ;)